# Get all members of the facebook group

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

There is: "All of the users who are members of this group (can only currently return the first 500 members)." in the facebook graph api group documentation. If i has group with more than 500 members, how can i got all members of the facebook group?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{
  "data": [
  ], 
  "paging": {
    "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/<>/members?limit=5000&offset=0"
  }
}
```